# Detecting url (link) in the text cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in excel that consists of 3 columns:

```
--------------
|ID|Name|Info|
--------------
```

IN the info column there is some text that includes the citation and link to the source. But, somehow they are not recognized as hyperlink (i.e. - not clickable). The links always preserve the format:

```
(http://www. .....) or (https://www. ....)
```

They are always surrounded by braces and are on the new line.

How can I automatically convert these links inside text cells into hyperlink? I tried using autocorrection, but doesn't work. Even when I select the text and make a rightclick - there is no hyperlink option.

Any assistance is appreciated. Even if the solution is using macros.

**UPDATE: Example of the text in cell**

```
The information in this cell is about Google (http://www.google.com) and taken from Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should come nearer to what you wish to achieve. An unlimited number of links are converted to functioning hyperlinks, written to column `Info` and to the right of it (or to `C` number of columns to the right of `Info`. Please observe the comments in the code.

```
Sub ExtractLinks()
    ' 18 Jan 2018

    Const TargetClm As Long = 3                 ' 3 defines column C
    ' hyperlinks are written to TargetClm
    ' and to the columns to the right of TargetClm

    Dim Txt As String
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim n As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        ' Info is in column C, starting from row 2:
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, TargetClm).End(xlUp).Row
            C = 0               ' set C = 1 to not over-write original cell value
                                ' and start writing to the right of TargetClm
            With .Cells(R, TargetClm)
                Txt = .Value
                Do
                    n = InStr(Txt, "(")
                    If n Then
                        Txt = Mid(Txt, n + 1)
                        n = InStr(Txt, ")")
                        If n Then
                            .Offset(0, C).Formula = "= HYPERLINK(""" & Left(Txt, n - 1) & """)"
                            C = C + 1
                            Txt = Mid(Txt, n + 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop While n
            End With
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to see how your macro behaves, but I am getting "Application defined or object defined error" =(

Comment: you need to put the URL in quotes, so write `"= HYPERLINK(""" & Left(Txt, n - 1) & """)`

Comment: @Fun Thomas - Yes. Thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected the published code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert them in their own cell you would require VBA - simple, but this is simpler:-

Insert a blank column next to the `Info` column. Enter this formula in row 2. Adjust the reference to column C in the formula to point at your `Info` column.

```
=HYPERLINK(MID($C2,2,LEN($C2)-2))
```

Copy the formula down as required. This should create hyperlinks in the new column. Select all of them, Copy and Paste > Values in place. Delete the original column. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, this was clear. The problem is that the cell contains not only the link but some information + link. So, I don't want the whole cell to be a link, but just a part of it. And, the cell can contain 2-3 links as reference

Comment: See added example

Comment: Your new question is different from the original - and incomplete. For example, if there are several links, where would you like to put them? There can only be one functioning hyperlink in any one cell.

Answer (score 0):

To convert them "in-place", select the cells and run this short macro:

```
Sub hyperMaker()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If Left(v, 1) = "{" And Right(v, 1) = "}" Then
            If Mid(v, 2, 4) = "http" Then
                vv = Mid(v, 2, Len(v) - 2)
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:=vv, TextToDisplay:=v
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```